# Jsf получение данных и DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

Как из JsF обращаться к колонкам DataTable .По каким id&?как происходит обращение внутрь к элементу

Comment: какой элемент вы хотите получить? откройте страницу в браузере и посмотрите на этот элемент. какой у него id?

Comment: а есть какието  способы обращения через jquery к datatable columns

Comment: вы не понимаете как работает javascript! в браузере клиента нет никаких колонок из БД. есть HTML, JavaScript и CSS. все! колонки, jsf и пр есть только на сервере!

Comment: так это я понел ,я понел что jsf генерируется в html на стороне клиента и если в заранее известно значение можно к нему обратиться но просто интересно меня путает этот Expression Languagу

Comment: именно связь Js с Java  я непонимаю как 2 языка могут обмениваться инфой

Comment: либо закройте свой вопрос, либо уточните его

Comment: если имелось в виду интерактивное взаимодействие пользователя с данными в таблице, то можно посмотреть пример здесь - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml Это фреймворк Primefaces, и при его использовании можно обходится без написания Javascript-а на JSF страницах

Comment: С Expression Language всё просто. Выражение вычисляется и его результат выводится в итоговый html. А с какой целью нужно обратиться к колонке? Возможно эту задачу получится решить и без явного обращения.

Comment: Да спасибо Сергей я уже учусь понемногу э

Comment: уже понимаю суть jsf нечего иное как обректа потом она у клиента будет преображать html .Хотя путаница еще есть поверх моих айди добавляются какието уникальные айдишки

Comment: jsf нужны эти уникальные id-шники, чтобы получать данные формы, чтобы обновлять/изменять куски страницы с помощью ajax.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей я 2 дня задаю вопросы по jsf вмне отвчаете  не уставая.Очень приятно .а где можно про эти айдишки прочитать???и Еще у меня такая проблема в Jsf есть Dtable и его Colum-ы как мне к ним обращаться??немогу их проиденцифитировть.Если ответе с Jsf дальше уже все сам разберу вот мой вопрос .Прошу взглянуть

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609706/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-xhtml