# Как проиденцифитировать xhtml?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jsf

Есть Xhtml разметка енерирующая HTML в разметке таблица и столбцы ... Хочу со скрипта обратиться к таблице но не получается присвить им идентификатор .Когда генерируется HTML в нем идентификаторов нет. Как с этим бороться другие фреймворки не предлогать пока учусь этому .Буду рад за содеенную помощь

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:link outcome="create" value="Insert a new employee"/>
        <h:form id="myform">

            <h:dataTable value="#{empControl.lst}" var="em">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header" class="Myclasis" >ID</f:facet>
                    #{em.id}
                </h:column>
                <h:column id="adi">
                    <f:facet name ="header">Name</f:facet>
                    #{em.name}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Address</f:facet>
                    #{em.addr}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                   <f:facet name ="header">Email</f:facet>
                    #{em.email}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Phone</f:facet>
                    #{em.phone}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Actions</f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink value="Remove" action="#{empControl.remove(em)}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')"></h:commandLink>
                    <h:commandButton value ="Edit"
                                     action="#{empControl.edit(em)}"></h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>

        </h:body>
</html>
```

Хочу получить и обращаться путем селектров как в Css .Кто с таким сталкивался сделайте мне подарок  помогите )Ещё раз спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо задать id таблице. `<h:dataTable id="mydt" ...` Тогда html будет `<table id="myform:mydt" ...`. Принцип формирования id в jsf - добавление через `:` своего id к родительскому id. Такой полный id называется clientId.

Используя такие id совместно с css, надо помнить что `:` имеет какое-то специальное назначение в css, поэтому его надо экранировать.

Ещё один способ - это биндинг компонента к какому-нибудь бину. `<h:dataTable binding="#{mydt}" ...` Это создаст в request scope UIDataTable под именем `mydt`.  Тогда для получения id таблицы можно использовать выражение `#{mydt.clientId}`.
("Прибиндить" можно и к полю своего бина какого-нибудь, главное чтобы он был requestScoped)

Теперь зная id таблицы можно в скрипте получить элемент:
`var table = document.getElementById('myform:mydt');` или
`var table = document.getElementById('#{mydt.clientId}');` если используется биндинг.

Далее, имея элемент таблицы, пройти по строкам и/или ячейкам.

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        // col - ячейка i,j
    }
}
```

Или селектором jquery что-то выбирать, используя id таблицы как некую отправную точку. `$('#myform\:mydt .Myclasis')...`
Не помню надо ли в jquery экранировать `:` и как правильно, но на всякий случай попытался как умею.
Если id получать из биндинга, то надо будет сделать функцию экранирования `:`.